# How to manipulate nodes with using networkx (Python3, twitter, networkx)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, twitter, networkx

I'm a beginner who try to make followers network of twitter with Python3. I made this code and got result however always one node is separated as you can see like left bottom node. [image]

I have no idea what is happening. In addition, I also want to see smaller world for instance, how can I pick up only 5 friends and elucidate their connection ?? This my result is too huge... It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain the details. Here is my code :

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key = my_consumer_key,
              consumer_secret = my_consumer_secret, 
              access_token_key = my_access_token_key, 
              access_token_secret = my_access_token_secret, 
              input_encoding = "UTF-8",
              sleep_on_rate_limit=True)


friends = api.GetFriends()

G = networkx.Graph()

for friend in friends:
    G.add_edge(myname,friend.screen_name)


for friend in friends[-3:]:
    for user in api.GetFriends(friend.id):
        if user in friends:
            G.add_edge(friend.screen_name,user.screen_name)


pos = spring_layout(G)


draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size = 100, node_color = 'w')
draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width = 1)
draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size = 12, font_family = 'sans-
serif', font_color = 'r')

xticks([])
yticks([])
savefig("egonetwork.png") 
show()
```

Comment: You're asking a few questions at once. Stick to one at a time; post each separately.

Comment: I see. I will. Thank you.